# How to check status of RxBleConnection

Tags: rxandroidble

Is there some approach to check if the `RxBleConnection` instance is active or was disconnected? Or maybe some notification to track the moment of disconnection?

Answer (score 0):

RxBleConnection instance you receive in method onConnectionReceived when connection is successful, if ble get disconnected, RxBleConnection will fail to perform any operation like read/write which can be caught in call back to determine connection failed

However best approach will be to check on connection fail callbacks it self to determine connection is not active

Thanks
Swayam

Comment: What callback? I don't recall such in the library

Comment: When you try to create a connection like below :-             connectionSubscription = bleDevice.establishConnection(this, autoConnectToggleSwitch.isChecked())
                  .subscribe(this::onConnectionReceived, this::onConnectionFailure);                                                                                          in case of connection fails you will receive call back in onConnectionFailure method from which you can determine there is no active connection

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to keep the `RxBleConnection` open in a non-reactive way. In this situation you would need to keep the track of the connection state by yourself. You could do it with a helper class:

```
static class ConnectionWithState {
    RxBleConnection connection;
    boolean isActive;
}
```

And when establishing connection just do:

```
final ConnectionWithState connectionWithState = new ConnectionWithState();
final Subscription connectionSubscription = bleDevice
        .establishConnection(this, false)
        .subscribe(
                connection -> {
                    connectionWithState.connection = connection;
                    connectionWithState.isActive = true;
                },
                throwable -> connectionWithState.isActive = false,
                () -> connectionWithState.isActive = false
        );
```

And disconnecting would need you to unsubscribe from the `connectionSubscription`.

Best Regards